# RxJs/Redux/Angular - Dynamic sort functions from multiple observable streams

Tags: angular, sorting, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I have an angular application that is using NGRX as a state store for data coming from an API.

The primary data in the application is a collection of inventory items. Each item has properties that are keyed to child collections. (ie. manufacturerId is keyed to a collections of manufacturers, etc.) I am using ngrx-entity in order to be able to index the collections.

I want to display this data in a grid on the screen in a denormalized fashion (display manufacturer name instead of id), and then allow them to sort by any of these columns.

The trick here is, that I need to sort by data that is in a child collection, and that child collection is an observable stream itself. The only "subscribe" in this whole process is in the HTML markup with an "async" pipe - and I plan to keep it that way.

I want to be able to apply the sort field and the sort direction dynamically, but I am not quite sure how to do it efficiently. I have created this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-observable-sorting) of how I have it working now. However, the example only shows 2 child fields, and I have another half dozen fields to sort by. The code could get rather messy.

Plus at some point, I will be adding some kind of filtering to this as well.

I've considered modifying the API to return the data denormalized, but that seems like a less than ideal approach, as there are data integrity issues.

Here's the code for the stackblitz as it stands now. I'm looking for some feedback to make this better.

```
import { of, BehaviorSubject, timer } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, combineLatest, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const manufacturers = {
  1: { id: 1, name: 'Acme' },
  2: { id: 2, name: 'Swift' },
  3: { id: 3, name: 'Baker' }
};

const styles = {
  21: { id: 21, code: 'Bridgeport' },
  22: { id: 22, code: 'Summit' },
  23: { id: 23, code: 'Anderson' },
  24: { id: 24, code: 'Saturn' }
};

const couplerTypes = {
  1: { id: 1, name: 'Barringer' },
  2: { id: 2, name: 'Waldorf' }
};

const inventory = [
  { id: 123, manufacturerId: 1, styleId: 21, couplerTypeId: 1},
  { id: 124, manufacturerId: 2, styleId: 21, couplerTypeId: 1},
  { id: 125, manufacturerId: 1, styleId: 23, couplerTypeId: 2},
  { id: 126, manufacturerId: 3, styleId: 24, couplerTypeId: 2},
  { id: 127, manufacturerId: 3, styleId: 22, couplerTypeId: 1},
  { id: 128, manufacturerId: 1, styleId: 22, couplerTypeId: 2},
  { id: 129, manufacturerId: 3, styleId: 24, couplerTypeId: 2},
  { id: 130, manufacturerId: 2, styleId: 21, couplerTypeId: 1},
  { id: 131, manufacturerId: 2, styleId: 21, couplerTypeId: 1},
  { id: 132, manufacturerId: 1, styleId: 24, couplerTypeId: 2},
]

// Assume these four collections are coming from an NGRX store
const manufacturers$ = of(manufacturers);
const styles$ = of(styles);
const couplerTypes$ = of(couplerTypes);
const inventory$ = of(inventory);

// Sort functions
const sortAscending = (one, two) => (one > two ? -1 : 1);
const sortDescending = (one, two) => (one > two ? 1 : -1);

// Start with sort descending
const sortDirection$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(sortDescending);

// An observable of a function that sorts by manufacturer name combined with the sort direction
const manufacturersSort$ = manufacturers$.pipe(
  combineLatest(sortDirection$),
  map(([manufacturers, sortDirection]) => {
    return (one, two) => sortDirection(
      manufacturers[one.manufacturerId].name,
      manufacturers[two.manufacturerId].name);
  }));

// An observable of a function that sorts by style code combined with the sort direction
const stylesSort$ = styles$.pipe(
  combineLatest(sortDirection$),
  map(([styles, sortDirection]) => {
    return (one, two) => sortDirection(
      styles[one.styleId].code,
      styles[two.styleId].code);
  }));

// A stream of a stream of sort functions
const sortFunction$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(manufacturersSort$);

// The combination of the inventory and the sort function
const sortedItems$ = sortFunction$.pipe(
  switchMap(innersort$ => innersort$.pipe(
    combineLatest(inventory$),
    switchMap(([innersort, items]) => {
      return of(items.sort(innersort));
    }),
  ))
)

// SHow me the output
timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
  sortDirection$.next(sortAscending);
  timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
    sortFunction$.next(stylesSort$);
    timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
      sortDirection$.next(sortDescending);
    });
  });
});

sortedItems$.subscribe(items => {
  items.map(item =>console.log(`id: ${item.id}, manufacturerId: ${item.manufacturerId}, styleId: ${item.styleId}, couplerTypeId: ${item.couplerTypeId}`));
  console.log('--------------------');
});
```

Comment: Flattening this structure would be an obvious decision in my opinion. Think about all the lookup you would avoid in your filtering and sorting logic (especially the sorting logic). And you dont necessarily need to change your api, you could also transform the incoming data to a structure that is easier to filter.

Comment: Flattening is an option, and I have looked into it. I've even implemented it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-observable-sorting-flat?file=index.ts However, I am still left feeling wanting on a more elegant way to dynamically sort. Flattening only eliminated the repeated lookups.

Comment: Ill see if i can find a better way if i find the time. Code looks clean btw